# How do I retrieve a value in the IMemoryCache by the key provided on the API call

Tags: .net-core

I have been playing around with the .Net Core Web API and have been trying to get the key and value that I have stored in cache. I store it in cache using the following statement:

```
if (!cache.TryGetValue<string>(store.id, out string failureString))
        {
            _cache.Set<string>(store.id, store.name);
        }
return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { store.id, store.name });
```

With the JSON:

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"Tesco"
}
```

But I am unsure what I need to put in the below method in order to return the id and value depending on what parameter is used on the api call?

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {

    }
```

Is this at all possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what exactly you're asking and the problem.

Comment: I have some items stored in the cache (using IMemoryCache) and I am trying to retrieve them.  The closest I have gotten is by using  'return Ok(_cache.Get<int>(id));' But this is defaulting to 0.  How would I go about outputting what I have stored in IMemoryCache?  Thank you.

Comment: i think you need to use Get<string> because the value you're saving is a string (name), and also, can you publish the declaration of `_cache` and tell me if it is a class member ?

Comment: Thanks Orel. Yeah you were right, I realised I was overcomplicating the solution and I just needed to use the .Get(id) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with the following:

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return Ok(_cache.Get(id));
    }
```